# Customize Proof Environment but "Missing $ inserted"

Tags: environments

I'm using XeLaTeX and Overleaf and I want to define a new proof environment that looks like:

> `\begin{pf} some texts... \end{pf}` 证明. some texts...
>
> `\begin{pf}[1] some texts... \end{pf}` 证明一. some texts...

(The Chinese words should be in `\heiti`, which is defined in the ctex package)

However, Overleaf keeps saying **Missing $ inserted**. Also, I found out that many characters are missing. I don't know what mistake(s) I made.

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{zhnumber}

\newcounter{pfnum}
\newenvironment{pf}[2][0]{%
\setcounter{pfnum}{#1}
\ifnum #1=0 \par\noindent\heiti 证明.\hspace{1em}\noindent
\else \par\noindent\heiti 证明\,\zhnum{pfnum}\,.\hspace{1em}\noindent 
\fi
}
{\hfill \qedsymbol}


\begin{document}
\begin{pf}
Test.
\end{pf}

\begin{pf}[1]
$$P(x+1,y)$$. 一二三。
\end{pf}

\begin{proof}
Test.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're defining `pf` with one optional argument and one mandatory argument. Do `\newenvironment{pf}[1][0]{...}{...}` (same code inside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `pf` to have a mandatory argument after the optional one, but you just want the optional argument.

I'd use the standard `proof`, so you don't get into problems with the final qed.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{zhnumber}

\newcounter{pfnum}
\newenvironment{pf}[1][0]
 {%
  \setcounter{pfnum}{#1}%
  \begin{proof}[\heiti 证明\ifnum#1>0 \,\zhnum{pfnum}\,\fi]
 }
 {\end{proof}}


\begin{document}
\begin{pf}
\[
P(x+1,y).
\]
一二三。
\end{pf}

\begin{pf}[1]
\[
P(x+1,y).
\]
一二三。
\end{pf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `$$` in LaTeX in the document body. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

```tex
\newenvironment{pf}[1][0]{%
\setcounter{pfnum}{#1}
\ifnum #1=0 \par\noindent\heiti 证明.\hspace{1em}\noindent
\else \par\noindent\heiti 证明\,\zhnum{pfnum}\,.\hspace{1em}\noindent 
\fi
}
{\hfill \qedsymbol}
```

Comment: `\hfill \qedsymbol` isn't enough if the last line of the proof text is (nearly) full; the box will fall at the beginning of the next line.  Copy that code from `amsthm`.